# Angular and Rails not able to create a user with the data sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a Rails 4 api with devise gem with an angular frontend. When i send a user json object the post parameters are sent but rails doesn't seem to like the format:

The Json object sent from the angular to the rails api is:

```
Resource {first_name: "test first", last_name: "test last", email: "test@test.com", password: "testpass", password_confirmation: "testpass"}
```

but the data is received by rails as:

```
 Parameters: Parameters: {"first_name"=>"test first", "last_name"=>"test last", "email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "first_name"=>"test first", "last_name"=>"test last"}}
```

and fails on the validation: ["Password can't be blank"]. Which shows it expects the **user** object format, but why isn't the password and password confirmation being added here?

I'm not sure whether i'm doing something wrong with Angular or Rails. If i send a request from Angular formatted as:

```
$scope.user = new User({user: {first_name: 'test first',
                last_name: 'test last',
                email: 'test@test.com',
                password: 'testpass',
                password_confirmation: 'testpass'}});
```

then this works:

```
 SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 29 Jun 2014 11:25:47 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$p70dQldL.b1SnyQFacr9YechtPOxLLNCjyuawiY/iPJGu4YgoQYV."], ["first_name", "test first"], ["last_name", "test last"], ["updated_at", Sun, 29 Jun 2014 11:25:47 UTC +00:00]]
```

but $scope.user = new User(); doesn't. Here is my code:

Users angular controller:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('UsersCtrl', ['User', '$scope', '$route', function(User, $scope, $route) {
            $scope.user = new User();
            $scope.users = User.query();

            $scope.save = function() {
              $scope.user.$save();
              $scope.users.push($scope.user);
              $scope.user = new User();
            };
          }]);
```

Angular users service

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('User', function($resource) {
          var User = $resource('http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/users/:id.json', {id: '@id'}, {
            update: {
              method: 'PUT'
            }
          });

          return User;
        });
```

user rails controller

```
          def new
            respond_with(User.new)
          end

          def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save
              render :json => { :success => true }
            else
              Rails.logger.debug @user.errors.full_messages
              render :json => { :errors => @user.errors.full_messages }, :status => :unprocessable_entity
            end
          end

      private
      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
```

angular view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="save(user)">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputFirstName">First Name:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" ng-model="user.first_name"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputLastName">Last Name:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputLastName" ng-model="user.last_name"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" ng-model="user.email"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputPassword" ng-model="user.password"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPasswordConfirmation">Password Confirmation:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputPasswordConfirmation" ng-model="user.password_confirmation"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create user</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```